# skip first line from text file while inserting into sql table

Tags: python, mysql

I have text file employee.txt and i am inserting it into sql table but i am getting 1st line same with headers followed by my table values.I am very new to python.how do i remove that first line in table which is header.

```
inpfile=open('C:/Users/chari/Documents/employee.txt','r')
while 1:
    line=inpfile.readline()
    if line=='':
           break
    serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city=line.split()
    stmt = ("""insert into employee(serial_no, first_name,last_name,age,sex,city)""" +"values"
        +str((serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city)))
    cursor.execute(stmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Use `with` to read file and then use `next()` to skip first line.

**Ex:**

```
with open('C:/Users/chari/Documents/employee.txt') as infile:
    next(infile)   #Skip first line. 
    for line in infile:
        serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city=line.strip().split()
        stmt = ("""insert into employee(serial_no, first_name,last_name,age,sex,city)""" +"values"
            +str((serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city)))
        cursor.execute(stmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each line of a file with a for loop, but calling next() on the file will skip the first one and the for loop will continue from the 2nd:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    f = iter(f)
    first_line = next(f)
    for line in f:
        # .... do stuff with each line...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like **this**:

```
with open('C:/Users/chari/Documents/employee.txt') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city=line.strip().split()
        stmt = ("""insert into employee(serial_no, first_name,last_name,age,sex,city)"""     +"values"+str((serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city)))
        cursor.execute(stmt)
```

If you need first line for different purpose, then you can do something like **this** after opening your file

```
first_line = next(f)
```

Or you can open you file this way, storing whole file into the variable. This solution can be used to read any line, so it feels better to me. But it's gonna be taxing if you are working with a very big file:

```
f = open('C:/Users/chari/Documents/employee.txt','r')
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
f.close()
```